# De la tabla, crear una función que imprima el histograma de las calificaciones y su media

Tags: c

Este es codigo para imprimir la tabla , lo que falta es imprimir el historama y la media que no se como hacerlo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char A[20][3][20];
    int i;
    FILE *fptr;

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("Enter Name=");
        scanf("%s",&A[i][0]);
        printf("\nEnter qualification and difference for %s=",A[i][0]);
        scanf("%s%s",&A[i][1],&A[i][2]);
    }

    fptr = fopen("fileopen.txt","w");

    if(fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fptr,"| Name |qualification|difference|");

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fprintf(fptr,"\n| %s | %s | %s |",A[i][0],A[i][1],A[i][2]);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: es obtener el      *histograma

Comment: En el examen no vas a tener [es.so]  a tu disposición. Piensa que deberías empezar a currarte las soluciones por tu cuenta y acudir aquí solo para atascos puntuales... Con la pregunta anterior a la actual ya deberías saber recorrer un array... empieza por ahí para sacar el histograma y pregunta cuando te atasques en ese punto. Es mi consejo

Answer (score 0):

para hacer el cálculo de la media de todas las calificaciones, debes tomar las calificaciones y a continuación sumarlas, por último dividirlas entre la cantidad de calificaciones totales, algo como esto:

```
int A[20][2]; //imaginando que ya tienes los datos en dicha matriz
int i, suma;
float media;
for(i=0, suma=0;i<20;i++)
    suma = suma + A[i][1];
media = suma / 20;
```

No se lo que es la *difference*, así que, si para calcular la media necesitas usar también dicha variable, dime que es lo que guarda dicha variable.

Comment: es la diferencia

Comment: Entonces, incluye también la diferencia para poder calcular correctamente la media de todas las calificaciones.